# Cassandra issue while adding jmx_prometheus

Tags: cassandra, prometheus, jmx

I want to add Cassandra monitoring using Prometheus. ref https://blog.pythian.com/step-step-monitoring-cassandra-prometheus-grafana/

When I add /etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh

`JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -javaagent:/opt/jmx_prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7070:/opt/jmx_prometheus/cassandra.yml"`

I get an error :

```
ubuntu@ip-172-21-0-111:~$ sudo service cassandra status
● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2020-04-13 05:43:38 UTC; 3s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3557 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/cassandra stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3570 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 13 05:43:38 ip-172-21-0-111 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: distributed storage system for structured data...
Apr 13 05:43:38 ip-172-21-0-111 systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed storage system for structured data.
ubuntu@ip-172-21-0-111:~$ nodetool status
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.
```

when I remove jmx_prometheus entry I get it working :

```
ubuntu@ip-172-21-0-111:~$ nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.21.0.111  1.83 GiB   128          100.0%            b52324d0-c57f-46e3-bc10-a6dc07bae17a  rack1
```

ubuntu@ip-172-21-0-111:~$ tail -f /var/log/cassandra/system.log

```
INFO  [main] 2020-04-13 05:37:36,609 StorageService.java:2169 - Node /172.21.0.111 state jump to NORMAL
INFO  [main] 2020-04-13 05:37:36,617 CassandraDaemon.java:673 - Waiting for gossip to settle before accepting client requests...
INFO  [main] 2020-04-13 05:37:44,621 CassandraDaemon.java:704 - No gossip backlog; proceeding
INFO  [main] 2020-04-13 05:37:44,713 NativeTransportService.java:70 - Netty using native Epoll event loop
INFO  [main] 2020-04-13 05:37:44,773 Server.java:161 - Using Netty Version: [netty-buffer=netty-buffer-4.0.36.Final.e8fa848, netty-codec=netty-codec-4.0.36.Final.e8fa848, netty-codec-haproxy=netty-codec-haproxy-4.0.36.Final.e8fa848, netty-codec-http=netty-codec-http-4.0.36.Final.e8fa848, netty-codec-socks=netty-codec-socks-4.0.36.Final.e8fa848, netty-common=netty-common-4.0.36.Final.e8fa848, netty-handler=netty-handler-4.0.36.Final.e8fa848, netty-tcnative=netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork15.906a8ca, netty-transport=netty-transport-4.0.36.Final.e8fa848, netty-transport-native-epoll=netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.36.Final.e8fa848, netty-transport-rxtx=netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.36.Final.e8fa848, netty-transport-sctp=netty-transport-sctp-4.0.36.Final.e8fa848, netty-transport-udt=netty-transport-udt-4.0.36.Final.e8fa848]
INFO  [main] 2020-04-13 05:37:44,773 Server.java:162 - Starting listening for CQL clients on /172.21.0.111:9042 (unencrypted)...
INFO  [main] 2020-04-13 05:37:44,811 CassandraDaemon.java:505 - Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it
INFO  [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2020-04-13 05:37:46,625 ApproximateTime.java:44 - Scheduling approximate time-check task with a precision of 10 milliseconds
INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2020-04-13 05:37:46,752 CassandraRoleManager.java:339 - Created default superuser role 'cassandra'
```

Comment: Have you checked the port connectivity between Prometheus and Cassandra node?

Comment: Ok will check it thanks

Comment: @LetsNoSQL  Btw Cassandra has to just export and shouldn't bother if Prometheus or any service like new relic is reading it or not while starting Cassandra service as in my case Cassandra should get started irrespective of  Prometheus and Cassandra node connectivity ! am I right ?

Comment: as you added Prometheus agent property in cassandra-env.sh so when you will start Cassandra it may prevent to start. As you also mentioned that after removing the property Cassandra is working as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked! Changed port to 7071 from 7070 in JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -javaagent:/opt/jmx_prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7071:/opt/jmx_prometheus/cassandra.yml"

Comment: Good, 7071 port may be opened already so it is access while restating Cassandra.